# Graph Transform

Tags: graphing-functions

How do can I transform the first graph into the second. Methods, answers, any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell if something complicated is going on with such little detail, but it looks like $g(x) = f(x) - 0.5$ does the trick, where $f(x)$ is the first function and $g(x)$ is the second.